# Cant get Total of NULL value and cant configure table properly

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to get the Total by using `COUNT` and `SUM` in my query, I was able to get the other value but not the NULL values.

If you would notice, NoUpdate does not have any value in the screenshot. But there is definitely NULL value in my table.

Also I cant seem to fixed the resulting table as I want my table to look like below,
[Correct Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ChWd.jpg)

Here is my code,

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$date = $_POST['date'];
$date1 = $_POST['date1'];

$sql ="SELECT 
    COUNT(IF(status='Successful', 1, NULL)) as `Successful`
    , COUNT(IF(status='Failed', 1, NULL)) as `Failed`
    , COUNT(IF(status='Canceled', 1, NULL)) as `Canceled`
    , COUNT(IF(status='RolledBack', 1, NULL)) as `RolledBack`
    , SUM(IF(status='IS NULL', 1, NULL)) as `NoUpdate`
    , COUNT(status) as `Total`
    FROM table
    WHERE date_implemented BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date1'
    GROUP BY Status";

$myData = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

$output = 
"<tr>
<th colspan='5' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px; border-top:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>Status</th>
<th width='auto' align='center' rowspan='2' style='border:dotted 1px; border-top:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width='auto' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>Successful</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>Failed</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>Canceled</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>RolledBack</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>NoUpdate</th>
</tr>\n";

$totSuccessful = $totFailed = $totCanceled = $totRolledBack = $totNoUpdate = $totAll = 0;
while (list($successful, $failed, $canceled, $rolledback, $noupdate, $total) = mysql_fetch_row($myData)) {

    $output .= "
        <td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;'>$successful</td>
        <td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;'>$failed</td>
        <td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;'>$canceled</td>
        <td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;'>$rolledback</td>
        <td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;'>$noupdate</td>
        </tr>\n";
    $totSuccessful += $successful;
    $totFailed += $failed;
    $totCanceled += $canceled;
    $totRolledBack += $rolledback;
    $totNoUpdate += $noupdate;
    $totAll += $total;   
}
$output .= "<tr></th>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totSuccessful</td>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totFailed</td>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totCanceled</td>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totRolledBack</td>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totNoUpdate</td>
<td align='center' style='border-bottom:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'>$totAll</td></tr>\n";

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

UPDATE:

I edit the code as suggested by Gordon Linoff and I was able to get the correct table now.

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'Successful') as `Successful`,
       SUM(status = 'Failed') as `Failed`,
       SUM(status = 'Canceled') as `Canceled`,
       SUM(status = 'RolledBack') as `RolledBack`,
       SUM(status IS NULL) as `NoUpdate`,
       COUNT(*) as `Total`
FROM table
WHERE date_implemented BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date1';
```

[Fixed Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJRBq.jpg)

But still missing the value for the NULL - NoUpdate column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this to:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'Successful') as `Successful`,
       SUM(status = 'Failed') as `Failed`,
       SUM(status = 'Canceled') as `Canceled`,
       SUM(status = 'RolledBack') as `RolledBack`,
       SUM(status IS NULL) as `NoUpdate`,
       COUNT(*) as `Total`
FROM table
WHERE date_implemented BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date1';
```

Notes:

- The operator you want is `IS NULL` not `= 'IS NULL'`.  The latter is a string comparison.
- I simplified the logic, taking advantage of the fact that MySQL treats boolean expressions as operators.
- I removed the `GROUP BY`.
- I changed the last expression to `COUNT(*)` from `COUNT(status)`.  `COUNT(status)` only counts the non-`NULL` values . . . and the name `Total` suggests that you want everything.

You could also put each status on a separate row:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table
WHERE date_implemented BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date1'
GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the correct table now. But still missing the NULL value. Please see my update with the  screenshot.

Comment: Thanks...this is already resolved...its just the date apparently which cause the NoUpdate not to show...so noob...